# Loading a string into a local variable dynamically

Tags: assembly, nasm, fasm

Suppose, I've created a local variable in stack or rather allocated memory for a string and now I want to put a value in it.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0xff ; 255 bytes
```

And storing strings in the stack in C:

```
strcat(my_str1, "something1");
strcat(my_str1, get_var2());
strcat(my_str1, "something3");
strcat(my_str1, get_var4());
```

I want to undertand how to do that without "strcat" in FASM or NASM:

```
;1
mov byte ptr [esp - 1], 's'
mov byte ptr [esp - 2], 'o'
mov byte ptr [esp - 3], 'm'
mov byte ptr [esp - 4], 'e'
; and so on
```

Is this how it's done? And about the part with "get_var2()" and "get_var4()"?

```
;2
call get_var2
mov ??byte?? ptr [esp - 11], eax
; or lea?
```

Comment: Try to implement `strcat` in C first (without using any library functions). Then you see how it works, and you can do the same in asm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `sub esp, 0xff` keep `esp` aligned, at least per 4. If you need only 255 bytes for C string (254 chars + zero terminator), then allocate 256.

2) `mov [esp-1],'s'` You already decremented `esp`, so the local variable is at some `[esp+X]` address (how much depends how many other values you did push on stack). Or rather use `[ebp-Y]` with C-like function prologue, initializing stack frame pointer in `ebp` first (`push ebp` `mov ebp,esp` `sub esp,local_vars_size` .. then epilogue `mov esp,ebp` `pop ebp` `ret`).

But never touch values UNDER `esp`, unless you know exactly what you are doing and why (like writing into red zone in 64b mode), because if you are not sure, then in 99% it will end as bug, and very often one of those difficult to find, which affects the code only rarely.

3) in NASM those 4 movs can be done with single dword constant `mov [esp-4],dword 'emos'` (BTW, you probably did want to set `'some'`?)

And yes, that's the common way how compiler set up shorter constants in locally allocated stack space, for bigger data they may use `memcpy` from constant template data.

4) about `get_var2()`, so `get_var2()` returns stable `(char *)` pointer? Then you will have to reimplement full `strcat`, unless you can tell how many chars are already in the string, and how many will be added. If `get_var2()` returns some value, you have first convert it to some characters and decide how many, etc.. then you can write them directly, or in some loop, etc. Too broad.

Also when operating on local stack, I would allocate some safety space around your variables in case you go beyond boundaries and overwrite few bytes over. And you even may set up those extra bytes to some canary value first, and then check it upon function end, to see if some stack overwrite happened (in debug builds at least). And instead of `strcat` you then need `strncat` or similar, to avoid stack overrun by malicious data.

Otherwise as Jester suggest, maybe try to implement just `strcat` first, on fixed memory buffers, so you can focus on the code itself, not resolving allocation of local memory. Then you may build upon it, even use it as function call.

Comment: `1) sub esp, 0xff keep esp aligned, at least per 4. ` -- why 4?

Comment: @Kevin: on x86 you will mostly get away even with unaligned memory access (but paying considerable performance penalty). But with certain SIMD (and FP?) instructions you will get crash on illegal memory access (that usually requires 16B alignment and is usually mandatory in 64b calling convention, but not in 32b). Just due to performance reasons it's considered bad-enough practice to never do that. It doesn't even have any benefits, except sparing 1-3 bytes, that's not relevant in x86 world (even data structures are padded just to make its members aligned, wasting much more bytes than this).